# React increment state from component

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to create a filtered table similar to the react example here: [Thinking in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html). What I would like to add is a count of how many items are being displayed out of the total set of items. My idea was to keep the state variable 'numShowing' in the top level component "Resources". I also created a function in this component to increment 'numShowing' using setState(). I then pass that function down the chain of components and call it when the component of interest is mounted. Here is some psuedo-code (I have removed unnecessary stuff and references to the filtering component):

The component hierarchy is: Resources -> ResourcesTable -> ResourcesTableEntry.

```jsx
var Resources = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      numShowing: 0
    };
  },
  incrementShowing: function() {
    console.log('increment from: ' + this.state.numShowing);
    this.setState({numShowing: this.state.numShowing + 1});
  },
  render: function() {
      <div>
        <ResourcesTable resources={this.state.resources} incrementShowing={this.incrementShowing} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ResourcesTable = React.createClass({
  createEntry: function(resource) {
      if (/* filtered out */) {
        return;
      } else {
        return(<ResourcesTableEntry key={resource.id} resource={resource} incrementShowing={this.props.incrementShowing} />);
      }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <table>
          <tbody>
            { this.props.resources.map(this.createEntry) }
          </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var ResourcesTableEntry = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.props.incrementShowing();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <tr>
        /* output props here */
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

I also tried incrementing from the ResourcesTable.createEntry function. In both cases, numShowing only ever gets set to 1. I assume this is because setState is asynchronous or non-atomic, so the current state of numShowing is 0 at the point every call to incrementShowing() is made (console output verifies the function is being called the correct number of times). So what would be the "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't want to update state within the render method, as it is an anti-pattern.  The problem can be solved by moving the filtering to the component which will own `numShowing`, i.e. `Resources`.  This would happen to eliminate the need for the `ResourceTable` component.

```
var Resources = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    numShowing = 0;
    filteredResources = this.state.resources.map(function(resource){
      if (/* filtered out */) {
        return;
      }
      numShowing++; 
      return(<ResourcesTableEntry key={resource.id} resource={resource} />);
    }.bind(this));
    return(
      <div>
        <span> Number of results: {numShowing} </span>
        {filteredResources}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```